# Xcode 8.3.2 giving compile errors for third party frameworks

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am using Xcode version 8.3.2 which is giving following errors for every third party framework. I'm using swift language.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some related codes?

Comment: why dont use Cocoapods?

Comment: @Raptor - I have just completed my UI code without any third party framework. Till then all goes WELL. For network operation I just added Alamofire and Argo using cocoapods. Then during build I got these errors.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari - I already added frameworks using cocoapods. I am not adding manually.

Comment: Does Cocoapods show any error / warning during `pod install`? Sometimes you have to take extra step after using `pod install`. Also, make sure you're launching the `xcworkspace`.

Comment: pod update and start xcode and clean build

Comment: @Raptor - no warning. Yes I am opening xcworkspace always.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari - ok. will try.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari - I first used pod update. Then started xocode -> clean -> built again. But same errors.